# Jquery decode JSON

Tags: jquery

I'm passing encoded JSON from Jquery to another Jquery function. I'm stuck on how to decode it. This is how I encode the JSON:

```
    var searchObject = {};
    searchObject['type'] = 'indexBottomBanner';
    searchObject['gender'] = $('.indexBodySearchLookingForActiveWrapperDIV').attr('data-gender');
    searchObject['age'] = $('#indexBodySearchAgedSelectedSPAN').attr('data-aged');
    searchObject['country'] = $('#indexBodySearchCountrySelectedSPAN').attr('data-country');
    ajaxInternalPageChange('search', 'anchor', JSON.stringify(searchObject));
```

I can see (when I log to console) the JSON is correctly formed.

How can I then take encoded object and decode it? And how do I access a variable within it like gender?

thanks

Comment: use JSON.parse( param  ) or direct pass  searchObject without JSON.stringify.

Comment: @Adam try with jQuery.parseJSON(searchObject);

Comment: @Adam have you checked our answers ?  it will help you or not?

Answer (score 0):

decode

```
JSON.parse(searchObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse( param  ) or direct pass  searchObject without JSON.stringify.

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fcsavjz/1/)

```
  var searchObject = {};
  searchObject['type'] = 'indexBottomBanner';
  searchObject['gender'] = 'male';
  searchObject['age'] = '20';
  searchObject['country'] = 'india';
  ajaxInternalPageChange('search', 'anchor', searchObject);

function ajaxInternalPageChange(search, anchor,searchObject){
   alert(searchObject.gender)
}
```

check link with [jsfiddle](http://JSON.parse(searchObject);)

using

```
JSON.parse(searchObject);
```